# Including source files at compile time with VB.NET and Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

As usual, I do my research in the various forums.  My personal discipline is that if I have struggled for more than a day, I need to reach out for help.  Because after a day, I can no longer see the wood because of the trees.

My web site has some code written in VB.NET which I use on many pages of the web site.  Where possible, I try to write code only once.  For obvious reasons.  I include the code in a class.
However, when I use a class, I cannot access the page controls.  For example, the HTTP context is available on the VB.NET code-behind but not in the class declared in the code-behind.  Is there some way of achieving this result?

Another option is to have VB.NET code in a separate source file.  And to include this source file into the main source code file at compile time.  If I need to make a change, I can do it in the source code
“segment” once only.  Right now, if I want to make a global change, I have to cut and paste through many web pages.   I have read that this type of “include” was possible in VB prior to VB.NET.  I can find no reference to this for VB.NET in Visual Studio.  Any suggestions?

For example if this code is to be run on every web page, how would you set it up so that you only have one source?  That is called on 150 pages?

```
Protected Sub getCookieVariable()
    '
    Dim myCookieName As String
    Dim myCookieValue As String
    '
    myCookieName = "hfl3"
    Dim myCookie As HttpCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies(myCookieName)
    If Request.Cookies(myCookieName) IsNot Nothing Then
        myCookieValue = myCookie.Value
        myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30)
        Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie)
        session("myCookieValue") = myCookieValue
    End If
    '
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you not have your class take an argument in a constructor or method and have the page pass itself in, then access what you need via that reference in the class.

Comment: `public shared sub ClassMethod(HttpContext ctx)/end sub`

Comment: Hi T.S.  You may be on to something here.  However, the answer you have given does not really lead me in the right direction.  Would you care to expand on your answer?